# SSIS Package Migration error

Tags: ssis

I am working In a Project where I am migrating SSIS Packages from 2008 to 2016. In 2008 packages They have used a third party component named Blue SSIS. I am trying to open 2008 package I am getting an error due to that component. can anyone help me out on this?

ERROR:

> The Task with the name Blue SSIS+FTP and the creation name "SSIS
>   Replacement Task" is not registered for use on this computer.

Comment: Ask "Them" where they got the component and add it to your machine and the 2016 server.

Answer (score 0):

Blue SSIS+FTP comes from http://bluessis.com/Index.aspx?PageId=FTPComponent

This page http://bluessis.com/Index.aspx?PageId=AboutBlueSSIS indicates they support 2005-2014 so you'll need to confirm with them that they have componentry that targets SQL Server 2016.

Once you have the 2016 component installed on your machine, you'll then need to upgrade/replace the 2008 version with the 2016. Third party components don't auto-upgrade like the Microsoft shipped ones do.